# How can I set mysql system variables in spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I'm struggling with the situation below

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

The query that makes above error is like below

```
where key = concat(cast(a.id as char), '-', cast(b.id as char))
```

`key` column's charset and collation is `utf8mb4 + utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.
And our mysql server's `character_set_connection`, `collation_connection` are also same above.

```
mysql> show global variables like '%c%'
-----------------------------------------------
character_set_connection | utf8mb4
-----------------------------------------------
collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci
-----------------------------------------------
```

According to this settings, above exception should not occurred.
But in spring boot, the result of `cast` operator seems to be converted `utf8mb4_general_ci`.

I didn't set system variables when spring boot startup.
What did I wrong?
My jdbc url like below

```
jdbc:mysql://{host}:3306/{database}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul
```